# Factoring out shared data validation using Python decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have the following two functions in a class of a project:

```
def stage_changes(self, change_set_name):
    change_set_id = self._get_change_set_id(change_set_name)
    # Perform validation on change set ID
    self._stage_changes_internal(change_set_id)

def commit_changes(self, change_set_name):
    change_set_id = self._get_change_set_id(change_set_name)
    # Perform validation on change set ID (same validation as first function)
    # Perform some other computation using change set ID
    self._commit_changes_internal(change_set_id, ...)
```

I'm looking to factor the first two shared lines out of these functions, namely

```
change_set_id = self._get_change_set_id(change_set_name)
# Perform validation on change set ID
```

My questions:

1. Does using a decorator actually make sense here, or am I trying to be too creative in a place where I should just be calling a simple helper function?
2. If it *does* make sense to use a decorator, how would I go about structuring it? It seems as though it might be cumbersome to do so, given that I need the value computed in the common epilogue to perform additional computation in each function(i.e. the shared logic does more than just produce a side-effect, it returns a value).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you can apply the DRY principle using a helper function.
I think its more about personal taste, using a helper or decorator function here.
But as a decorator, it could look like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def validateData(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        cls = args[0]
        change_set_name = args[1]

        if change_set_name in ('bar', 'foobar'):
            kw['change_set_id'] = 1
        else:
            kw['change_set_id'] = None

        return fn(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper


class Foo():
    @validateData
    def stage_changes(self, change_set_name, change_set_id=None):
        print('change_set_id in stage_changes:', change_set_id)
        # Perform validation on change set ID
        #self._stage_changes_internal(change_set_id)

    @validateData
    def commit_changes(self, change_set_name, change_set_id=None):
        #change_set_id = self._get_change_set_id(change_set_name)
        print('change_set_id in commit_changes:', change_set_id)
        # Perform validation on change set ID (same validation as first function)
        # Perform some other computation using change set ID
        #self._commit_changes_internal(change_set_id, ...)

f = Foo()
f.stage_changes('bar')
f.stage_changes('banana')
```

Prints:

```
change_set_id in stage_changes: 1
change_set_id in stage_changes: None
```